# "Lost" sigtrap when debugging with gdb on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, gdb

In my usage scenario, I've got GDB on Mac debugging an inferior X. A separate process Y keeps sending SIGTRAPs to X (using kill(pid, SIGTRAP)) in quick succession, which should be caught and handled by GDB.

The Mac version of GDB has a thread that waits on the exception ports for process X. When Y sends a signal to X, it shows up on the exception port for X as an exception message (using the kernel's "softsignals") feature.

The problem I'm running into is, every now and the corresponding exception message is not received by GDB on X's exception port, even though a signal was sent by Y to X.

I tried using dtrace to make sure the kernel sees the signal being sent, but I'm doing something wrong, dtrace does not show anything for any process:

```
sudo dtrace -n 'proc:::signal-send /pid/ { printf("%s -%d %d",execname,args[2],args[1]->pr_pid); }'
```

...does not show any sigtraps being sent by Y to X, even though GDB handled them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In Linux, most signals will be lost if one is already signalled. Maybe in OS X this is also true? Perhaps TRAP isn't handled before the new one comes in.